# How do I get read and write percentages?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, disk-io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Qsi.jpg)

I'm trying to get the value shown in the image in Windows 10 using Python. I have studied similar questions on this resource but have not found any working variant or clear instructions to get the desired value.